# Get Clob Value From Cursor in Plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to retrieve clob value from my cursor with appended each loop data. I tried to reach clob value like
`R_SER_HIZ_MST."XMLTYPE".GETCLOBVAL()` command but when I use this with   `DBMS_LOB.APPEND(CLOBTORETURN,v_TEMPLOB);`I am getting numeric or value error. Am I doing something wrong or what to do for getting clob value and append with another clob then return this clob(in this case CLOBTORETURN) from function ?

My Plsql Function Code :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SOS_TABS.GET_CALL_LIST(    P_IK_KOD           IN VARCHAR2,
                                                          P_ORG_KOD      IN VARCHAR2,
                                                          P_SER_KOD      IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2
      IS
    
    
        CURSOR C_SER_HIZ_MST (vc_servis_org_kod VARCHAR2, vc_servis_ser_kod VARCHAR2, vc_ekodenekbel_param VARCHAR2) IS
            SELECT VALUE(table_temp) AS "XMLTYPE"
              FROM XMLTABLE ('/ROWSET/ROW' PASSING
              DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE('
                   SELECT *
              FROM SER_HIZ_MST "shm"
                INNER JOIN SER_SERVIS_TNM "sst1"
                  ON "shm".ORG_KOD = "sst1".ORG_KOD
                  AND "shm".SER_KOD = "sst1".SER_KOD
                INNER JOIN SER_BELGE_TIP_TNM "sbtt"
                  ON "shm".BELGE_KOD = "sbtt".BELGE_KOD
                INNER JOIN SER_SEHIR_TNM "sst"
                  ON "shm".ULKE_KOD = "sst".ULKE_KOD
                  AND "shm".SEHIR_KOD = "sst".SEHIR_KOD
                INNER JOIN SER_ILCE_TNM "sit"
                  ON "shm".ULKE_KOD = "sit".ULKE_KOD
                  AND "shm".SEHIR_KOD = "sit".SEHIR_KOD
                  AND "shm".ILCE_KOD = "sit".ILCE_KOD
                INNER JOIN SER_MUSTERI_TNM "smt"
                  ON "shm".MUS_ID = "smt".ID
              WHERE "sst1".ORG_KOD = (CASE WHEN ''' || vc_servis_org_kod || ''' IS NOT NULL THEN ''' || vc_servis_org_kod || ''' ELSE NULL END
                )
                AND "sst1".SER_KOD = (
                CASE WHEN ''' || vc_servis_ser_kod || ''' IS NOT NULL THEN ''' || vc_servis_ser_kod || ''' ELSE NULL END
                )
                AND "shm".IK_KOD = ''' || P_IK_KOD || '''
                AND "sbtt".BELGE_KOD = ''' || vc_ekodenekbel_param || '''
                AND "shm".DURUM = ''ACIK''
                ')
              ) table_temp;
    
       v_TEMPLOB CLOB;
       CLOBTORETURN CLOB;
    
    BEGIN

dbms_lob.CREATETEMPORARY(CLOBTORETURN,TRUE);--iniatialize clobtoreturn here
  dbms_lob.open(CLOBTORETURN, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);
  dbms_lob.append(CLOBTORETURN, '{"results":[');
    
    FOR R_SER_HIZ_MST IN C_SER_HIZ_MST(V_SERVIS_ORG_KOD, V_SERVIS_SER_KOD, V_EKODENEKBEL_PARAM)
        LOOP
    SELECT R_SER_HIZ_MST."XMLTYPE".GETCLOBVAL() INTO v_TEMPLOB FROM DUAL;
       DBMS_LOB.APPEND(CLOBTORETURN,v_TEMPLOB);
    
        END LOOP;
    
    RETURN CLOBTORETURN; 
    END;
```

My Environment : Oracle 11g database

Answer (score 0):

Try to `getclobval` directly in your cursor without need to select it from dual into temporary clob. Without example data and structures it is hard to answer what went wrong.

Another option is to extend `LISTAGG` function to `LOB` arguments, like [in this post](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/iuiyzdd8z4jquuca86yxq8s60). This looks for me more flexible way. Then you can get a single row with clob and export it to json array.

What about the original code, below code completed successfully for me (I excluded select from dual):

```
QL> set echo on
SQL> 
SQL> create or replace function f_clobify( p_dummy varchar2)
  2  return clob
  3  is
  4    lv_ret_clob clob;
  5  begin
  6    dbms_lob.createtemporary(lv_ret_clob, true);
  7    dbms_lob.open(lv_ret_clob, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);
  8    dbms_lob.append(lv_ret_clob, '{"results":[');
  9  
 10    for r in (
 11      select VALUE(table_temp).getclobval() AS val
 12      FROM XMLTABLE (
 13        '/ROWSET/ROW'
 14        PASSING DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE(replace(q'[select '#val' as v from dual union select '#val_2' from dual]', '#val', p_dummy))
 15      ) table_temp
 16    ) loop
 17      dbms_lob.append(lv_ret_clob, r.val);
 18    end loop;
 19  
 20    dbms_lob.close(lv_ret_clob);
 21  
 22    return lv_ret_clob;
 23  end;
 24  /

Function F_CLOBIFY compiled

SQL> select f_clobify(dummy)
  2  from dual
  3  /

F_CLOBIFY(DUMMY)                                                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"results":[<ROW><V>X</V></ROW><ROW><V>X_2</V></ROW>
```